# Need a RegEx to eliminate < and >

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a C# RegEx pattern which can remove anything between `<` and `>`

E.g  if my string is

```
<Html> some stuff here 123445!@#$% </HTML>
```

then the RegEx should return me only

> some stuff here 123445!@#$%

It should remove anything between  `<` and `>` and then also remove "<" & ">"

Comment: Are you talking specifically about just the `<` and `>` characters and the characters in between? I.e. 123<456>789 would return 123789?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: look for escape html character. it is a common measure for xss.

Comment: @user1016253 Yes. I want anything between < and > to be removed and also < and >. So your example is perfect. 
So if have <something here> ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) more stuff </iEndHere> then output should be ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) more stuff

Comment: @Styne666 I have tried http://txt2re.com But i honestly admit , i am not good at this stuff. But I  know that RegEx will be better than looping the string. Hence posting here instead of writing crap looping  code.  :)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to [parse xml/html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3603).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
here is a working example : 

string plainText = Regex.Replace(htmlText, "<[^>]+?>", "");
```

http://regexr.com?2vl05

### edit

Im talking as interpreter :

**<** = search for '<' char

**[^>]** = now continue search for char which is **not** '>'

**+**  continue searching for more instances of it

**?** but dont be greedy

**>** when im saying dont be greedy - i mean - until i will encounter with '>'

**AND REPLACE THIS WITH ""**

Comment: This one is better than my example indeed, I forgot the exclusion class. Also the non-greedy flag is good

Comment: Thanks..Can you explain how do i read this ?  "<[^>]+?>" 
Any good links to learn basics of RegEx ? I have always ignored this topic :)

Comment: Why the lazy operator?? You try and match whatever is not a `>` until `>`! `[^>]` will _not_ match `>` anyway. So, quite the opposite, it could be a possessive operator if supported!

Comment: Ah, this is C#, so possessive quantifiers are not supported. Thus an atomic group could be used: `<(?>[^>]+)>` -- but a plain `<[^>]+>` is enough if you don't want to bother

Answer (score 1):

Something like: `\<.+\>?(.*)\<\/.+\>?`
Group one will be the string between the two tags

You could also do a regex replace on `\<\/?.+\>`, you should replace this pattern with nothing

Comment: `<`, `>`, and `/` have no special meaning in regexes; there's no need to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex with HTML might be a little bit dangerous, HTML is not a regular grammar and regex might fail in some notsoeasy to realize cases. If you are working with HTML and .NET, maybe you'd like to give a look to [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I will be doing this stuff at server side.